# How to work a Wireless Mic in Raspberry Pi 3 to make it a voice recorder?

Tags: pi-3, audio, wireless, bluetooth

We have been trying to connect Raspberry Pi 3 to Bluetooth headset with inbuilt mic. The audio out is working in the above scenario but not audio in. Does any body have any suggestions on how it can be accomplished?

Comment: I am trying to create a wireless voice recorder machine.

Comment: You're not giving much to go on here. What software are you using? What headset? How is it connected to the RPi 3 (built in bluetooth or a dongle)?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible [source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian/) :-

> Bluetooth support is limited at this stage; you can pair with pretty much anything, but you can only usefully connect to devices which support either the Human Interface Device or Audio Sink services – in other words, mice, keyboards and other UI devices, and speakers and headsets.

Comment: Actually now it should not be a problem of raspbian. I can get sound via a2dp profile yet in headset profile there is silence for both sink and source and this seems to be general bluez/pulseaudio problem ...